# I cannot loop through my JSON and fetch my data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, exception

I cannot seem to loop through my `syllables`, while I do the exact same thing with my `word`. This however does work, how come?

my JSON:

```
{
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "getExerciseTitle": "Example",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "application": "lettergrepen",
  "main_object": {
    "title": "Example",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "exercises": [{
      "word": "espresso",
      "syllables": [
        "es",
        "presso",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }]
  },
  "dataType": "json"
}
```

}

my loop for the `syllables`:

```
var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
$.map(exerSyll, function(exerSyll, s) {
  $(".syllable" + s).val(exercise.syllables)
});
```

the loop I have for my `word` that does work:

```
var exercise = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
$.map(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
  $("#addOpdracht").click();
  $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + i).val(exercise.word) 
});
```

where it should append the `syllables`:

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables',
    'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
   });
  return wpInput;
}
```

Is it possible to create one loop and append the `syllables` in the syllable inputs and the `word` in the exercise input? or does it have to be seperate loops? I would like to keep the desired `syllables` with the right `word` when I fetch it back to my CMS.

a picture to clarify: [image] I am trying to get the syllables with the desired word.

Comment: The first might not work because exercise is not declared, you are capturing the variable as exerSyll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `exerSyll`, in the `map` function callback, so it's hoisting the original declared `exerSyll` variable and that's why you get the `Ecxeption` in your code:

```
//First declaration of exerSyll 
var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

//Reusing the same variable exerSyll in the callback
$.map(exerSyll, function(exerSyll, s) {
  //Will cause an exception beacause exerSyll declaration will be hoisted
  $(".syllable" + s).val(exercise.syllables)
});
```

You should use another name to the variable in your callback to avoid the Exception.

```
var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {
  console.log(exer.syllables)
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a working demo, showing the problem resolution.

```js
var json = {
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "getExerciseTitle": "Example",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "application": "lettergrepen",
    "main_object": {
      "title": "Example",
      "language": "nl_NL",
      "exercises": [{
        "word": "espresso",
        "syllables": [
          "es",
          "presso",
          "",
          ""
        ]
      }]
    },
    "dataType": "json"
  }
};

var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {
  console.log(exer.syllables)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: urs indeed works. but I have a question now... if u don't mind I could post a picture so you get an idea of what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, what's the problem?

Comment: I editted my post with a picture so you get an idea of what I mean. I am trying to fetch the data with the right word and syllables back to my CMS you see, but will the code keep the syllables together with the word? or will the syllables start flying off? I want the syllables to join with the word itself. so they always stay in their own respective exercise block

Comment: @D.Sof You need to use only one loop to process both word and syllables.

Comment: Ah oke, is it possible to combine these 2 loops together? or will the structure completely change? I'm sorry for the amount of questions, i'm a newbie in javavscript / jquery

Comment: Oh, no problem, it's fine. Yes, you can wrap it all inside only one loop, just put the two statements inside your loops in one loop.